# Three docker containers with python image get mixed up in docker compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file in which I have three services, each being a python script that needs to be executed.

Each service has a dockerfile

- Dockerfile.scriptA
- Dockerfile.scriptB
- Dockerfile.scriptC

In a folder called "python_tools" I have three subfolders:

- scriptA
- scriptB
- scriptC

with each of them a file: main.py

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
    scriptA:
        image: python:3.9
        volumes:
        - ./python_tools/logs/scriptA:/opt/app/scriptA/log
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.scriptA
    scriptB:
        image: python:3.9
        volumes:
        - ./python_tools/logs/scriptB:/opt/app/scriptB/log
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.scriptB
    scriptC:
        image: python:3.9
        volumes:
        - ./python_tools/logs/scriptC:/opt/app/scriptC/log
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.scriptC
```

and each Dockerfile.scriptX:
(notice here that I start to use X for A,B, and C to prevent repetition where not needed)

```
FROM python:3.9
COPY ./python_tools/scriptX /opt/app/scriptX
WORKDIR /opt/app/scriptX
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "-u", "main.py" ]
```

Now, the main.py has the following code:

```
def log(msg):
    print(msg)
    f = open("log/log.txt", "a+")
    f.write(msg + "\r\n")
    f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    log("Starting scriptX")
    while(True):
        do_something()
```

The problem is that, once I execute:

```
docker logs -f python_scriptB-1
```

I get:

```
Starting scriptA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/app/scriptA/main.py", line xx, in <module>
    log("Starting scriptA")
  File "/opt/app/scriptA/main.py", line xx, in log
    f = open("log/log.txt", "a+")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'log/log.txt'
```

Notice that script B has launched the code from script A?
I'm not sure how this is caused. Maybe some caching issues but I'm not sure how to get rid of the cache in this case?

So the issue is that somehow, it looks like the wrong script code is launched for a script. So it might very well be that the container of scriptC launches main.py in scriptB etc.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a general better solution to my container/service setup?

During "docker compose build --no-cache" I already notice that scriptA is being build three times rather than scriptA, scriptB and scriptC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three containers are running the same image

```yaml
services:
    scriptA:
        image: python:3.9
    scriptB:
        image: python:3.9
    scriptC:
        image: python:3.9
```

You should delete these `image:` lines.

If a Compose service has both `image:` and `build:`, Compose uses `image:` as the name of the image it builds (see for example the [`build:` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build)).  If you leave off `image:`, Compose chooses a name for you.  If you're planning to `docker-compose push` the image to a repository then you should specify `image:` with the repository-qualified name; but if not it's safe to just leave out `image:`.

It doesn't matter that the three services have three different `build:` blocks to build that image, or that the image happens to have the same name as a Docker Hub image.  `docker-compose build` will build all of the images and then tag an arbitrary one as `python:3.9`, and then `docker-compose up` will run that single tagged image in all three containers.

In particular you should **not** set `image:` to match the `FROM` line in the Dockerfile.  This causes the Docker Hub image (in your case, `python:3.9`) to be overwritten with the result of the build, which can cause surprising behavior later.  `docker pull python:3.9` will re-fetch the image from Docker Hub and recover from this situation.